# Do Sequences automatically increment by 1?

Tags: oracle

If I leave out the "INCREMENT BY" in a sequence, does it automatically just increment by one? I am realizing I checked in code to start a sequence and left out the "INCREMENT BY" statement. However, once I view the sequence in my schema, It shows the sequence is set to incrementing by 1. Just trying to figure out if I need to check out that code and make changes or is it fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314) says:

> INCREMENT BY
> Specify the interval between sequence numbers. This
> integer value can be any positive or negative integer, but it cannot
> be 0. This value can have 28 or fewer digits for an ascending sequence
> and 27 or fewer digits for a descending sequence. The absolute of this
> value must be less than the difference of MAXVALUE and MINVALUE. If
> this value is negative, then the sequence descends. If the value is
> positive, then the sequence ascends. **If you omit this clause, then
> the interval defaults to 1.**

Comment: This is correct, but it's important to state that sequences do not produce numbers serially, in the presence of multithreading and rollbacks. That means they can produce gaps.